# Can I install Ubuntu on a system that does not currently have an operating system?

Tags: system-installation

Can I install Ubuntu on a laptop that has been wiped clean and does not currently have an operating system? I don't have a Windows system disk, only a recovery disk, which is useless.

Comment: What have you tried? A simple boot from installation medium will present you the option to install. I'm also curious as to why you even think about this could be a requirement.

Comment: He's not asking "how" but if he "can"...

Answer (score 17):

Simple answer yes.

Obviously you'll need some way to download the iso image and burn it to CD/DVD or stick it on a  memory stick.

Comment: +1, and all you will need is to ensure that your laptop can boot from the CD or USB or whichever media you are using to install Ubuntu.

Answer (score 14):

Ubuntu is an Operating System itself. As such, it's actually *intended* that you install it to a clean device.

You will need the [desktop ISO](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop), burn a DVD from it or [create a different bootable medium](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-desktop-latest), and you're pretty much good to go. Boot to whatever you created, and follow the instructions.

Comment: It's *fine* to install it to a clean device. This is, of course, not required--it works fine if there's already an OS installed.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is yes.

Just download iso file from ubuntu downloads and make a boot able device cd/flashdrive and start installing. search a bit in net about your lappy manufacturer in some cases ubuntu gives less battery time compared with windows.